# Is there a way to get terminal size from scala program?

Tags: scala

I heard that there is no pure, cross-platform solution. But maybe there are three separate solutions for most-used platforms (Linux, Mac, Win), which can be combined to get the needed value in most situations?

This needs to be included into a library, thus I can't add some sort of a pre-launch scripts to get the width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using JLine - specifically, you can use `Terminal.getTerminalWidth' to get the terminal width.

[JLine Terminal](http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jline/Terminal.html#getTerminalWidth%28%29)